# how to send / receive data from one smart contract to another smart contract

Tags: solidity

I have created 2 contracts in solidity and trying to deploy the contract using (geth console, mist browser). Seller and Buyer.

In seller contract, I am creating seller name, productquantity, perunitcost. In the buyer contract, I am creating buyer name.  Now I want to read the data of seller in the buyer contract, so that the buyer can make a purchase. How can I read data from one smart contract to another? Kindly help

Comment: so, did you manage to implement it?
and is it just me or do i only see errors in the gif posted?
spent almost a week now with solidity, having gone through all the docs, and what not before that and barely see anything functional..

Answer (score 5):

It's pretty easy, you can refer to another contract by address and call its functions if they are public:

```
 contract Foo {
    uint public value = 123;
  }

  contract Bar {
  Foo foo;
    function MyContract(address otherAddress) {
      foo = Foo(otherAddress);
    }
    function getFooValue() constant returns(uint){
      return foo.value();
    }
  }
```

See the fiddle in action:
https://ethfiddle.com/T-9cXyBwgI
[image]